# How to access a global variable in the WordPress "system" from a custom service?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, session, woocommerce

Hia,

VERY new to WordPress - so sorry if it does not make much sense :-)

More specifically this is about the WooCommerce plugin.

For all the files I have dabbled with - I am helping a friend BTW - to create a few nifty shortcodes for him, I have been able to just access the global $woocommerce.

This global variable had some neat methods, and I was able to find an API for it - so all was well.

Now I, for various reasons, need to create a small custom service that just changes the shipping country for the customer.

This I would previously be able to do by just doing like this - if I wanted to quickly hard set it to Bangladesh (I think it is)

```
<?php
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->customer->set_shipping_country("BD");
?>
```

Now naturally, in my set-customer-country.php service file I am not able to just waltz in and take advantage of this class made global with all cart contents etc..

So - my question is, how DO I get access to this, am I able to send across some sort of session ID that I can ask the system to please give me something in return for if I ask nicely by the right function and provide a valid session ID?

Thank you in advance, know at least I will get some attempts at helping :-)

Comment: The global `$woocommerce` has been deprecated in favor of the function `WC()` which returns the single instance of the `WooCommerce` class.

Comment: Thank you helgatheviking, good to know :-)

Answer (score 1):

Seems WordPress has a nice AJAX hook system in place.

So I have to create my function, register it with said system, and in my javascript I can access the URL for this call via the url "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"

```
    function cool_foo_func () {

        $response = array(
            "foo" => "func"
        );

        wp_send_json($response);
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_foo_func', 'cool_foo_func');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_foo_func', 'cool_foo_func');
```

And make the ajax call and just remember to call with the parameter action="foo_func" (or extend the object or whatever or how you do it)

So now I can write the service the same place where I am writing the shortcode, and my problem is solved :-)

Comment: Yes, also did this in code - was error in posting fix.
Thank you for pointing that out, will edit